# Removing freeze time forever

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive, server-administration

I would like to remove freeze time on my CS:GO Multi-1v1 server (hosted on dathost.net).
I can put `mp_freezetime 0` in the console but that only last for a round.

Is there a way to apply this change permanently?
To which config file should I put the command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried to add the command to `server.cfg` but the value was ignored.

Appending `mp_freezetime 0` to `csgo\cfg\sourcemod\multi1v1\multi1v1.cfg` solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to it (FTP or web interface) you'll want to change that setting in your server's `server.cfg`, which is located in your servers *csgo/cfg/* directory.

Whatever you put there will be permanent as it will be executed every map change.

However, if you want to customize more settings it's recommended to use a custom config file. Just upload it to */csgo/cfg/* and give it a proper name, like `1v1.cfg`. Put all your custom settings there and leave them alone in the `server.cfg`. Now add the line `exec 1v1.cfg` (or whatever you named your custom config) to the bottom of your `server.cfg` when you want to use those settings and remove it when you're done. Of course this also works with multiple different configs.